# Shorter timeout on connect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winsock

`connect` is failing with `WSAETIMEDOUT`. That's fine but is there anyway to make the timeout period shorter? Maybe something like 2-3 seconds? Currently it seems to be something higher like 10 seconds.

OS is Windows, using Winsock with C++

Comment: possible duplicate of [WINSOCK - Setting a timeout for a connection attempt on a non existing IP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199122/winsock-setting-a-timeout-for-a-connection-attempt-on-a-non-existing-ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the socket into non-blocking mode before calling `connect()`.  When it returns with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error, call `select()` with whatever timeout interval you want.  If `select()` reports the socket becomes writable, the connection was successful.  If `select()` reports a timeout instead, close the socket.

Comment: On my PC default (blocking) connect timeout is 3+6+12+24=45 seconds. Is it safe to close socket in non-blocking mode before this interval expires ?

Comment: @truthseeker: The interval for the default connect timeout on any given PC is not guaranteed.  And yes, you can close the socket before it times out.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before: [WINSOCK - Setting a timeout for a connection attempt on a non existing IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199122/winsock-setting-a-timeout-for-a-connection-attempt-on-a-non-existing-ip)

No, it's handled by the IP stack. You'll have to start a timer and kill the connection if you need to change this functionality.